# Retornar um valor de um cálculo de duas variáveis para mostrar ao usuário usando POO. Resultado não é printado na tela

Tags: java

```
Scanner deltas = new Scanner(System.in);
            Double ds;
            System.out.println("Insira o valor de Delta S");
            ds = deltas.nextDouble();
            setDeltas(ds);

            Scanner deltat = new Scanner(System.in);
            Double dt;
            System.out.println("Insira o valor de Delta S");
            dt = deltat.nextDouble();
            setDeltat(dt);

            Double velo = ds/dt;

            System.out.printf ("Sua velocidade media é: ", velo);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use apenas um `Scanner`.
2. Use o `printf` corretamente. Ou use o `println`.

Seu código corrigido:

```
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.println("Insira o valor de Delta S");
            double ds = sc.nextDouble();
            setDeltas(ds);

            System.out.println("Insira o valor de Delta S");
            double dt = sc.nextDouble();
            setDeltat(dt);

            double velo = ds / dt;

            System.out.println("Sua velocidade média é: " + velo);
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado!